# How to enable Dev UI in Docker container

Tags: docker, quarkus

I like to use Dev UI in our dev environment (Docker).
If I start the application by quarkus:dev locally, I can reach the Dev UI sites e.g.:

http://localhost:8080/myroot/dev/

http://localhost:8080/myroot/health-ui/

http://localhost:8080/myroot/logging-manager-ui/

However, when I run the application in docker with `-Dquarkus.profile=dev` no Dev UI site is reachable anymore. My service endpoints and swaggerui are however working.

I scanned https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config for Dev UI related config properties but didn't find any

Any idea how I can get Dev UI activated when my application is running in docker?

Answer (score 1):

Dev UI **only** works when you run `mvn quarkus:dev`, which is likely not what you are using to start the Quarkus application in a container

Comment: This is really sad :/ It would be super useful to have it on a dev environment activated. Is there any workaround/hack to get this working on docker? Only cumbersome approach I can imagine now, would be actually installing maven on the docker container and checking out the source there. Should I file a feature request in quarkus issue tracker?

Comment: There is no workaround, this has been done deliberately. You can certainly open an issue, but I am almost certain we won't ever provide this behavior (mainly for security reasons)

Comment: We have our dev env. running in a vpc and force authentication on all endpoints under host/myroot/ so I don't see the security argurment. I will try to create a proposal issue, wheras I wonder that no one else seems to have asked to have devui on a remote dev env.